# Armature deforming both feet when moving legs individually

Tags: armature

My object (body and feet) is one mesh. I sculpted the feet using a mirror modifier and then applied this modifier, and then joined the feet to the legs by fusing the vertices.

Now when I parent my mesh to the armature (with automatic weights) the legs are deforming the feet when I pose the legs (see images)

I tried weight painting the feet but it still does the same thing. Is there some vertex data that is pairing the two feet because I used a mirror modifier? Any help would be appriciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I tried to upload but I keep getting an 'internal error' message. Will try again later.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you showed of Weigh Paint mode has the lower left leg bone highlighted, but the problem is probably with the groups of the right-hand bones: One of the right leg vertex groups probably has vertices from the left foot in it. Check all those groups.

Comment: I'm using blender 3.2.0 so I'm not sure where the vertex groups are. It's not under object data anymore?

Comment: @ParadiseN Never was. It’s under the Mesh tab in the Properties editor.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to edit vertex groups before but this fixed it!